# how to increase the accuracy of Prophet model?

Tags: time-series, machine-learning-model, forecasting, prophet

I have a dataset representing the number of tickets over two years. I have used the prophrt model to predict make a prediction but the results don't seem to be accurate.
The code for the model is as follows:

```
model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=True)
model.fit(df_prediction1)

future_dates = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=360, freq='D')
forecast = model.predict(future_dates)
```

And the result was like this:
[image: Forecast results]

How to improve the accuracy of this model?